# SQL Query to select specific records from dates

Tags: sql, date, sorting, row-number

I have a table that has like a list of codes and the start and end date that the code was active. I want to select the most recent active codes. Which is simple enough but the part I'm getting stuck with is that you can have the same code with overlapping dates which means both are active and I'd need to select all these records. Or you can have the same codes but the dates follow on which means the previous one is no longer active and I want to ignore this.

See example of table below:

In the table below I'd essentially need to say okay this table if you have two of the same codes but the dates follow on then take most recent, if the dates overlap then select...

```
ID | Code | Start Date | End Date | I need to select
01 | A110 | 15/01/21   | NULL     | select
02 | A110 | 14/05/19   | NULL     | select
03 | A110 | 10/10/18   | 13/05/19 | Ignore
03 | B200 | 15/01/21   | NULL     | select
04 | B200 | 10/12/20   | 14/01/21 | Ignore
05 | C600 | 15/01/21   | NULL     | Select
```

Comment: hi, please specify the DBMS you are using and the query you've tried

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE END_DATE IS NULL
```

but maybe i got the question wrong, it really isnt clear at the moment

Comment: It looks like the other way round, ```WHERE end_date IS NULL```

Comment: @Max i see ignore where end date is not null...

Comment: Yes, OP apparently wants all entries where end data is NULL. And it's been some time since my prime SQL days, but if I remeber correctly that would be achieved by ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE end IS NULL;``` => ignoring all entries where end is not null

Comment: i really got that wrong, sorry